# Waiting for user input through GUI

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am new to java so this might be a stupid question.I want to stop my program until the user press enter .I have implemented Actionlistener but there is a message that I want to print after enter key is pressed.All I could think of is to implement a while condition but it does not seem to work.

```
public class main {

static JTextField field;
static int x;
public static void main (String [] args)
{   
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    field = new JTextField("field");
    panel.add(field);
    field.addActionListener(new action());
    while(x==0)//i want my program to stop here ,wait for user enter input and then  output below message
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "show message after user has preseed enter");

}
static public class action implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == field)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "user pressed enter");
            x=1;
        }

    }   

}
```

}

Comment: GUIs are event driver, Swing so single thread, so any blocking or long ruining operations will stop the UI and prevent from been updated or responding to user input. Based on what you seem to be trying to do, I'd recommend using a modal dialog of some kind

Answer (score 1):

GUIs are event driver, Swing so single thread, so any blocking or long ruining operations will stop the UI and prevent from been updated or responding to user input.

There are several ways you might be able to achieve this, you could use an observer pattern of some kind to receive event notification when the `ActionListener` is triggered, but based on what you seem to be trying to do, I'd recommend using a modal dialog of some kind.

Have look at [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JDialog frame = new JDialog((JFrame)null, "Help", true);
                frame.add(new FieldPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is after the dialog is closed");
            }
        });
    }

    public class FieldPane extends JPanel {

        public FieldPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
            add(field);
            field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(FieldPane.this).dispose();
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: and yes                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is after the dialog is closed");
does execute after i close the help window,but i cant understand how does the program does that.Is it because the program waits until user closes "help" dialog.If so it contradict with what you said"GUIs are event driver".

Comment: And can please show my how you can do it with observer pattern.Just direct me if there is any sample code available any where.I watched many tutorial on youtube and this one seems easy enough to understand(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56A_YY5frjo) but he is using observer pattern for a completely different thing.

Comment: Basically, this is how a modal dialog works. It stops the code's execution at the point the dialog is made visible, it's all a bit of black magic, but if you're really interested, essentially the dialog takes over the dispatching of events from the EDT.

Comment: `ActionListener` is a an example of an observer pattern (in fact all of Swing's Listeners are). The `ActionListener` doesn't care how the event is generated, only that it's notified when a specific "action" occurs.  Equally the `JTextField` doesn't care about the implementation of the `ActionListener` beyond the fact that it implements the `actionPerformed` method. Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841715/how-to-pass-data-between-two-jinternalframe/25842526#25842526) will help